# After deleting Ubuntu partition I get grub rescue> and can't boot Windows

Tags: windows, grubrescue

I was using two operating systems at my computer. Window 7 in partition (C:) and Ubuntu in partition (D:). I didn't need Ubuntu any more so I formated partition (D:) from Windows 7. Then I restarted the computer and it started showing this error:

```
Error: unknown filesystem.
Grub rescue >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Boot-Repair-Disk" https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/     Your boot information is still in your windows grub file, "Boot-Repair-Disk will fix your grub problem. Just follow instructions on the site above and you will be fine>